# Piecewise function and divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I'm having really a hard time!

Define the function $f$ as the following:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & \mbox{if } x \leq e \\ xf(\ln x), & \mbox{if } x>e \end{cases}$

And show that the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}$$ diverges.

I tried to prove divergence by using the integral test, but I'm hard time working with the functional equation $f(x) = x f(\ln x)$. 
I want to try to solve this by myself, could you just give me a hint?

Comment: I might say some really stupid but.... We should care about what happens before $e$ because if $lnx < e$ then it goes back to the first case, while if it's greater than $e$ it goes to the second case.

Comment: @qbert Does this really diverge? It seems to me it converges.

Comment: For example $f(5) = 5 f(ln(5) = 5 f(1.6) = 5* 1.6$

Comment: @grimx oh ooops good call

Comment: @qbert Ok thanks! So what would you look for divergence?

Comment: @grimx no no I was mistaken, you are right

Comment: @qbert No problem... this exercise it's harder than I thought..!!

Comment: @qbert I ran a simple program and it seems to converge to somewhere around $2.6$.

Comment: @OFRBG Are you sure?

Comment: @grimx No, but I added an answer. I'm open to criticism.

Comment: I'm still working on this. I've had other stuff to do, so I haven't found time to sit and play it out. I'll get it, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

If we go down the rabbit hole for $f(x)$, then we find that the form of the function is $x \times \ln(x) \times \ln(\ln(x)) \times …$. We can try an integral test (which I'm ashamed of not doing in the first place).

Our series is

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{f(n)} = \frac{1}{n \times f(\ln n)}
$$

Also you might consider that $f(e^y) = f(y)\ e^y$, where $x = e^y$. (Maybe useful.)

$$
\int \frac{1}{f(e^y)} \ \text{d}y = 
\int \frac{1}{e^y\ f(y)} \ \text{d}y = \int \frac{1}{y\ e^y\ f(\ln y)} \ \text{d}y 
$$

---

That's all I can do for today. Maybe you can pick it up from here. I'll work on this tomorrow!